# How to remove the OOB appearance category from the web part tool pane (editor part)?

Tags: web-part, toolpart

I am working on developing an (ASP.NET) web part for SharePoint 2010.

I have a requirement to not to show the Appearance and Layout category which gets displayed by default in the web part tool pane (editor part).

So I am seeking pointer through which I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Those Properties are stock standard with any Sharepoint webpart as you know.

I have not tested the following code, but i'm pretty confident that this should work:

```
    public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] myCustomToolparts = CreateMyCustomToolParts();

        //Removing the Base Method for calling creating the ToolParts should hide all the Built in Toolparts
        //return base.GetToolParts();

        return myCustomToolparts;
    }
```

If this does not work I'd suggest some Javascript/Jquery:

```
function hideToolParts(){
   $('#ctl00_MSOTlPn_EditorZone_Edit1g_55d19aab_008a_4d9a_9ca6_db3ad2137f20_LayoutCategory_IMAGEANCHOR').parent().hide();
   $('#ctl00_MSOTlPn_EditorZone_Edit1g_55d19aab_008a_4d9a_9ca6_db3ad2137f20_AppearanceCategory_IMAGEANCHOR').parent().hide();
}
```

Hope this helps.